# Float value resets after Adding

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, nsnumberformatter

I start off with a number, lets say 250. I add all sorts of numbers, but anytime I add a high number like 2,000 it adds correctly. Then I add 3. The new number comes out to 5 like it thought 2,000 was 2.0. I do not know why it is doing this.

```
float start = self.amountLabel.text.floatValue;
float changeAmount = self.amountField.text.floatValue;
float newValue;
if (determConfirm == 1) {
    newValue = start + changeAmount;
} else {
    newValue = start - changeAmount;
}

NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:5];

[formatter setRoundingMode: NSNumberFormatterRoundUp];
NSString *numberString = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:newValue]];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:numberString forKey:@"newValue"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

self.amountLabel.text = numberString;
self.amountField.text = @"0.00";
[self.amountField resignFirstResponder];
```

Comment: Could it be some locale mix-up? Some languages use `.`  as decimal separator, others use `,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the use of `floatValue` to convert the formatted number text to a number. `floatValue` only works as expected if the text is unformatted (no commas) and uses the period for the decimal separator.

Since you store a formatted number in the field, it only works with small numbers and in certain locales.

Replace your use of `floatValue` on the text with the same `NSNumberFormatter` used to format the number. Use it to parse the text and give you an `NSNumber` (which you can then call `floatValue` on).

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. instead of .floatvalue I used: float start = [[formatter numberFromString:self.amountLabel.text] floatValue]; and the same for changeAmount

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess as it's hard by looking at your code, but maybe you want this:

```
float newValue = start;

if (determConfirm == 1) {
    newValue += changeAmount;
} else {
    newValue -= changeAmount;
}
```